# Set a classpath on another machine by sourcing a script on that machine

Tags: python, shell, scripting

I have a script on machine B which sets a  classpath/PYTHONPATH on that machine.

If I source this script on machine B then it correctly sets the path on B.

However I need to source this script from machine A in which case PYTHONPATH is not set correctly.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: PYTHONPATH is not set correctly, means? Will you please give some example.

Comment: What OS? It would be helpful if we could see the script...